# In $\Delta ABC$, such that $\cos^2{A} + \cos^2{B} + \cos^2{C} = \sin^2{B}$, then $\tan{A} \cdot \tan{C} =$?

Tags: trigonometry

> In $\Delta ABC$, find the value of $\tan{A} \cdot \tan{C}$, such that $\cos^2{A} + \cos^2{B} + \cos^2{C} = \sin^2{B}$.

My idea is to substitute $\cos{B} = \cos{[\pi - (A+C)]} = -\cos{(A+C)}$ and $\sin{B} = \sin{[\pi - (A+C)]} = \sin{(A+C)}$ into the constraint to eliminate the variable B, then transform the constraint into an equation with the only variable $\tan{A}\tan{C}$. Then what I need to do is simply solving the equation and get the value of $\tan{A} \cdot \tan{C}$. But I'm stuck on the second step.

Dose anyone know how to simplify

$$\cos^2{A} + \cos^2{(A+C)} + \cos^2{C} = \sin^2{(A+C)}$$

into an equation in terms of the variable $\tan{A}\cdot\tan{C}$？

Comment: Please add some context or motivation. Right now it’s just an isolated problem.

Comment: @NotMath I've edited my question. Is that better?

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? If you mention that in addition then everything is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\cos(A-C)=k\cos(A+C)=-k\cos B$

$\implies k=\dfrac{\cos(A-C)}{\cos(A+C)}\iff\dfrac{k-1}{k+1}=\cdots=\tan A\tan C$

From the given condition,
$$\cos^2A-\sin^2C+2\cos^2B=0$$

$$\iff\cos(A-C)\cos(A+C)+2\cos^2B=0$$

$$\iff-\cos B(\cos(A-C)-2\cos B)=0$$

If $\cos B\ne0,k=-\dfrac{\cos(A-C)}{\cos B}=-2,\tan A\tan C=?$

Else $\cos B=0\implies B=\dfrac\pi2\iff A+C=\dfrac\pi2, A-C=\pm\dfrac\pi2, \implies A$ or $C=0$ which is impossible

Answer (score 0):

In a triangle $A + B + C = \pi$. Thus can write the equation as $cos^2A + cos^2C + cos^2(A+C) = sin^2(A+C)$ which can be further expanded as $cos^2A + cos^2C + cos^2Acos^2C + sin^2Asin^2C - 2sinAsinCcosAcosC = sin^2Acos^2C + sin^2Ccos^2A + 2sinAsinCcosAcosC.$

Rearranging, we get $cos^2A + cos^2C + (cos^2A - sin^2A)(cos^2C - sin^2A) = sin2A + sin2C = cos^2A + cos^2C + cos2Acos2C.$ Now using $sin2x = \frac{2tanx}{sec^2x}$ and $cos2x = \frac{1-tan^2x}{sec^2x}$ we get $cos^2A + cos^2C = \frac{4tanAtanC +tan^2A + tan^2C - 1 - tan^2Atan^2C}{sec^2Asec^2C}$.

Cross multiplying we get $2 + tan^2A + tan^2C = 4tanAtanC +tan^2A + tan^2C - 1 - tan^2Atan^2C$ which implies $tanAtanC= 1 ,3$.